# Android apk: duplicate entry: org/objectweb/asm/AnnotationVisitor.class

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, apk

My android project builds fine in android studio; but when I try to build the signed APK, I get the following error:

```
// Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'.
// > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/objectweb/asm/AnnotationVisitor.class
```

The full repository, at its current (immutable) snapshot, is [here](https://github.com/sanskrit-coders/stardict-dictionary-updater/tree/df3e0394db2dfddd44d16ee3baa2dd0b65d7430b). My best guess is that the dependency version changes from these two changes ([1](https://github.com/sanskrit-coders/stardict-dictionary-updater/commit/73648cf27566505e8a4d6ce912eaba2d06efcf1b), [2](https://github.com/sanskrit-coders/stardict-dictionary-updater/commit/253b4df73fcc2c3e201558c3c6d8777c9f5cf3ff)) caused the problem.

Dependency tree generated with `gradle app:dependencies` [here](https://github.com/sanskrit-coders/stardict-dictionary-updater/blob/master/dep_tree_android.txt), and I looked at the [android gradle plugin migration guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#variant_aware) without any flashes of insight.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Changing some proguard and build setting (which I deduced by comparing with a newly created empty project with the latest gradle version) fixed the problem - see [this changelist](https://github.com/sanskrit-coders/stardict-dictionary-updater/commit/7e6cc3753950b0c25170cd4c8ba72878e01fa0b3).